# Block android device from retrieving data from application server by device ID

Tags: android, security, android-security

I am developing an Android application that retrieves data from an external server. This application is installed on 20 tablets. However when a device is stolen, all access to this external server should be blocked, so no data can be retrieved from this external server.

I want to block the device by a Unique Device ID, so the server denies the identifier that the device sents to the server. I ended up with the so called [Android ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID). However it's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". It can also be easily changed on a rooted phone.

I know some banking applications block devices that were rooted in the past, so they use some way to block the device. I was wondering how they do that.

Is there a recommend way to achieve this device blocking?

Comment: Only unique id in android is imei. However - no sim-card is no id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- the App is not in Google Play
- was installed directly on the tablets
- you have control in what devices you will install it.

The best approach may be:

- to have in the back-end a white list of hashed device ids of all tablets the App is installed on.
- in each request to the back-end the App sends the hashed device id and a check is performed against the white list and only serves the request on positive match.

So if you control the devices where the App is being installed then you can ensure that is only installed in devices that do not return a `null` *ANDROID_ID*.

A better solution for your problem is to have an external service that can verify the integrity of your App at run-time in a way that the back-end can detect if each request does not come from a tampered App or rooted device. You can see an example of such a service in [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html).

On [this blog series](https://www.approov.io/blog/category/series-approov-tech.html) you can see a demo how Approov solution works and at same time learn other techniques to protect your App without the Approov solution, that uses an SDK integrated in your APP and a cloud service to verify the integrity of the App and device and emits a JWT token signed with a secret that only the cloud service and the back-end know, thus making it impossible to be reverse engineered in the device where the App is installed or by a Man in the Middle Attack.

Disclaimer: I work for Approov